# MongoDB retrieve sub level document values corresponding with aggregated field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb collection with the following structure.

```
/* 0 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5633cc4fd6f8ebfddf32fa77"),
  "contact_name" : "Fred Flintstone",
  "follow_up_date" : ISODate("2015-11-02T20:02:58.766Z"),
  "notes" : [
        {
            "author" : "Miles",
      "note_date" : ISODate("2015-10-30T20:00:15.735Z"),
      "note_text" : "Appointment requested via web interface",
      "source_type" : "appointment_request"
        },
        {
            "author" : "John",
      "note_date" : ISODate("2015-10-20T18:00:15.735Z"),
      "note_text" : "Phone support ticket",
      "source_type" : "web_support"
        }
    ]
}

/* 1 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("56381fe8d6f8ebfddf32fb8c"),
  "contact_name" : "Barney Rubble",
  "follow_up_date" : ISODate("2015-10-14T20:02:58.766Z"),
  "notes" : [
        {
            "author" : "John",
      "note_date" : ISODate("2015-10-30T20:00:15.735Z"),
      "note_text" : "Note entered",
      "source_type" : "note"
        },
        {
            "author" : "John",
      "note_date" : ISODate("2015-10-11T16:00:15.735Z"),
      "note_text" : "Account created",
      "source_type" : "account_activity"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to build an aggregation query such that I retrieve contact_name, follow_up_date, the maximum notes.note_date and it's corresponding notes.note_text and notes.source_type values.  Is this possible to do with a single call to "aggregate"?  So far my aggregation pipeline set is the following:

```
[
    {
        $unwind: "$notes"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { 
                lead_id: "$_id", 
                contact_name: "$contact_name", 
                follow_up_date: "$follow_up_date" 
            },
            "num_entries": { "$sum": 1 },
            "last_entry": { "$max": "$notes.note_date" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "contact_name": "$_id.contact_name",
            "follow_up_date": "$_id.follow_up_date",
            "last_entry": "$last_entry",
            "num_entries": "$num_entries",
            "lead_id": "$_id.lead_id"
        }
    }
]
```

This gets me everything I need except the note_text and source_type to go along with the "last_entry": { "$max": "$notes.note_date" } value.  Here is what is currently returned:

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "lead_id": "563c69a4d6f8ebfddf32fce0",
            "contact_name": "Barney Rubble",
            "follow_up_date": "2015-10-14T20:02:58.766Z"
        },
        "num_entries": 2,
        "last_entry": "2015-10-30T20:00:15.735Z",
        "contact_name": "Barney Rubble",
        "follow_up_date": "2015-10-14T20:02:58.766Z",
        "lead_id": "563c69a4d6f8ebfddf32fce0"
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "lead_id": "563c698fd6f8ebfddf32fcdf",
            "contact_name": "Fred Flintstone",
            "follow_up_date": "2015-11-02T20:02:58.766Z"
        },
        "num_entries": 2,
        "last_entry": "2015-10-30T20:00:15.735Z",
        "contact_name": "Fred Flintstone",
        "follow_up_date": "2015-11-02T20:02:58.766Z",
        "lead_id": "563c698fd6f8ebfddf32fcdf"
    }
]
```

And this is what I need:

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "lead_id": "563c69a4d6f8ebfddf32fce0",
            "contact_name": "Barney Rubble",
            "follow_up_date": "2015-10-14T20:02:58.766Z"
        },
        "num_entries": 2,
        "last_entry": "2015-10-30T20:00:15.735Z",
        "last_entry_source_type": "appointment_request",
        "last_entry_note_text": "Appointment requested via web interface",
        "contact_name": "Barney Rubble",
        "follow_up_date": "2015-10-14T20:02:58.766Z",
        "lead_id": "563c69a4d6f8ebfddf32fce0"
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "lead_id": "563c698fd6f8ebfddf32fcdf",
            "contact_name": "Fred Flintstone",
            "follow_up_date": "2015-11-02T20:02:58.766Z"
        },
        "num_entries": 2,
        "last_entry": "2015-10-30T20:00:15.735Z",
        "last_entry_source_type": "note",
        "last_entry_note_text": "Note entered",
        "contact_name": "Fred Flintstone",
        "follow_up_date": "2015-11-02T20:02:58.766Z",
        "lead_id": "563c698fd6f8ebfddf32fcdf"
    }
]
```

Comment: Would be really helpful if you could edit your question to include your expected result from the sample data.

Comment: Added current and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would introduce a **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** pipeline step just before the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline to reorder the document stream by the `note_date` key such that you can then apply the group accumulator operators **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** or **[`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last)**, which are only meaningful when documents are in a defined order. The operators will allow you to extract the whole denormalised `notes` document and then the **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** stage will do some field reshaping.

The final aggregation pipeline would look like:

```
[
    {
        "$unwind": "$notes"
    },
    { 
        "$sort": { "notes.note_date": 1 } 
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": { 
                "lead_id": "$_id", 
                "contact_name": "$contact_name", 
                "follow_up_date": "$follow_up_date" 
            },
            "num_entries": { "$sum": 1 },
            "last_entry": { "$last": "$notes" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "contact_name": "$_id.contact_name",
            "follow_up_date": "$_id.follow_up_date",
            "last_entry": "$last_entry.note_date",
            "last_entry_source_type": "$last_entry.source_type",
            "last_entry_note_text": "$last_entry.note_text",
            "num_entries": 1,
            "lead_id": "$_id.lead_id"
        }
    }
]
```